# "Всё хуже, чем я думала". На месте ли тут запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Всё хуже, чем я думала". Запятая точно нужна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это решение (запятую ставим) **чисто формальное,** но тем не менее применяется именно оно.

В действительности же здесь возможны д**ва интонационных и смысловых варианта:** (1) *Всё хУже, чем я дУмала (реальное сравнение).* (2) *Всё хуже чем я дУмала (всё плохо).*

Во втором предложении нет паузы и нет ударения на сравнительной степени. Оборот ***хуже чем я думала*** близок к устойчивому.

Но второй вариант встречается не часто, например:

― Худо, ― отвечал огорчённый отец, ― **хуже чем я думал**: она в беспамятстве бредит Валерианом. [А. С. Пушкин. Арап Петра Великого (1828)]

Так что не надо думать, что здесь **забыли поставить запятую.**

Answer (score 1):

Два простых предложения в составе сложного:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запятая нужна.